# ImportError: cannot import name 'http' from 'scapy.layers

Tags: scapy, python-3.7

I am getting this error and I don't understand why?

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'http' from 'scapy.layers
```

Here is my code:

```
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http  #error line


def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface,store=False,prn=p_s_p)

def p_s_p(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        print(packet)


sniff('wlan0')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485940/why-would-from-scapy-layers-import-http-generate-an-error/52486143

Comment: This is not part of the core scapy. There is a separate project you need to install for it: https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http  (probably you can use the `pip install` command shown in the README to install it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get scapy 2.4.3 http layer support to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447123/cannot-get-scapy-2-4-3-http-layer-support-to-work)

Answer (score 2):

To make things clear:

- `scapy-http` is **deprecated** starting from Scapy v2.4.3+.
- `Scapy 2.4.3+` now includes a modified (improved) version of `scapy-http` that is **disabled by default**, to be backward compatible. You can load it using:

  - `from scapy.layers.http import *`
  - `load_layer("http")` (if in the console)

Answer (score 0):

```
from scapy.layers.http import *
```

Finer points of scapy importing in python 3* are discussed in the following answer -- [Cannot get scapy 2.4.3 http layer support to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447123/cannot-get-scapy-2-4-3-http-layer-support-to-work)

Weirdly absent from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install scapy==2.4.5
```

It should fix your problem

Answer (score -2):

Use the scapy_http library:

`from scapy_http import http`

Comment: Or use this: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1925. It's the replacement of `scapy_http` that'll get merged in `Scapy` itself as the previous stopped his development :-p

Answer (score -2):

install the scapy http library from the terminal:

```
pip install scapy-http
```