# Cannot get scapy 2.4.3 http layer support to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I am trying to craft and manipulate some http packets with scapy and python 3. I have been unable to get http layer support to work.

I am using PyCharm for package management. I am on a Kali Linux virtual box. I have installed different version of scapy through PyCharm to no avail.

```
from scapy.all import *

explore(scapy.layers.http)
```

I would expect the results shown in the documentation (https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/http.html) but alas all I get is the following error message.

```
  File "<ipython-input-3-1b9771949c77>", line 1, in <module>
    explore(scapy.layers.http)

AttributeError: module 'scapy.layers' has no attribute 'http'
```

Please help, this is driving me absolutely insane. I've also tried it with conda on my main machine and gotten the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

The HTTP layer is currently not loaded by default (because it wasn't previously installed by default). You will need to load it manually via:

```
from scapy.layers.http import *
```

Or (mostly if you're using scapy's shell):

```
load_layers("http")
```

Note that `scapy-http` should *NOT* be installed. See the disclaimer https://github.com/invernizzi/scapy-http (it will soon be deprecated on PyPI too)

Comment: How do I import the load_layers function? If I use ```from scapy.all import *``` and then try to use it I get a name error.

Comment: ```from scapy.layers.http import *``` worked on both my set-ups btw, thanks for that.